# How to resolve Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' in vue library?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I created a library in vue using vue-cli and when i tried to import that library in another vue application it shows this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

To Build library

`"build-lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name testlib src/main.js"`

Entry point: **Main.js**

```
import TestButton from './components/TestButton.vue'
export default TestButton
```

Once i imported this library like this

`import DummyButton from 'dummylib'`

I am getting that error. I have been investigating this and couldn't solve this error.

What did i miss here?

Comment: i dont understand. why would you import someting, and export it again? i mean you already export it once?

Comment: sorry!!! where did i already exported already? i think i am exporting the component only in main.js right? correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: if you import it here `import TestButton from './components/TestButton.vue'` that means you have a `export` statement in this path `'./components/TestButton.vue'`